# how to rollback my local project folder using git?

Tags: git, github

my project files unfortunately deleted while using cursor wrongly pressed then i realised my project not deleted. i get each files  previous version of my git.my project  commited only in local git but not in github.com. i can see my project files in vs code commits(all what i want).i tried all the things but i cannot get my last commit  and i cannot overwrite and cannot get all deleted files in my local folder.

[image]

the above image show where my files stored in my last commit
i want every deleted files and overwrite all the changed files.

i tried but not work for me

```
git reflo

git reset --hard 9a0ffad
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Hash was wrong,i got all deleted and changed source file

before i tried

```
git reflo

git reset --hard 9a0ffad<------this hash was wrong
```

after (corrected hash )

```
git reflo

git reset --hard 5e0ffad<------after i changed correct hash
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete files, or commits?

If only the files are gone: `git checkout <your local branch>`

If this doesn't work, maybe git complains about unsaved changes, try this:

```
git checkout -f <your local branch>
```

or

```
git reset --hard
```

If commit disappeared, this gives you some kind of history of your previous git commands, with SHA1 number to commit that "disappeared": `git reflog`. These commits are probably still accessible and you can try to run `git checkout` on them.

Comment: ,i successfully get back my project source, i used "git reset --hard hash",my hash is wrong when i put correct one get started all my project source.thank u for help